# Applications in vs. applications to

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> I’m one semester away from completing my master’s studies of the
>   applications of eye tracking in/to interactive media.

In this context, what is the difference between

> the applications of eye tracking *in* interactive media.

and

> the applications of eye tracking *to* interactive media.

Or is one of them completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "to" is used, that makes "interactive media" the direct object: something/someone external applies eye tracking to interactive media.

When you use "in", that means "interactive media" is an adverbial: You apply eye tracking. Where? in interactive media, where interactive media is a collectivum for a lot of things, whereas in the other sentence it is a defined "object".

Answer (score 3):

I would use *in*:

> I’m one semester away from completing my master’s studies of the applications of eye tracking *in* interactive media.

As for my reason? It just sounds better. *Applications to media* doesn't make sense to me; *applications in media* does.

You have a string of prepositional phrases in this one sentence. You might consider rewording it slightly, to something like:

> I’m one semester away from completing my master’s studies on the way eye tracking can be applied in interactive media.